# How is windows task scheduler able to run interactive programs?

Tags: windows, windows-services

In latter versions of windows (I am using windows 10), windows services run in session 0 isolation which as far as I understand doesn't belong to any logged in user and means they cannot interact with users. If windows task scheduler runs as a service how is able to run interactive programs and the current logged logged in user? Is Microsoft using some back door API or is the something that I can do in services that I write myself?

Comment: The Task Scheduler service creates processes in other terminal sessions the same way that the Application Information service (i.e. UAC elevation) and Secondary Logon service (i.e. `CreateProcessWithLogonW`) work. A privileged system process can call `CreateProcessAsUser`, which requires a handle for an access Token. A Token is associated with both a logon session (`TokenLogonSid`) and a terminal session (`TokenSessionId`). Subsequently in the kernel, the `NtCreateUserProcess` system function creates the process in the target terminal session.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. If you would like to put together an answer which outlines which windows calls to make in which order and how any required parameters can be obtained, that can be used in a custom windows service, I'd be happy to accept.